# A complicated sorting problem

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

list = {{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {a, a}, {x, x}, {d}, {e}};
```

I want to sort the sublists with more than one element in descending
order by length and value and sublists with only one element in ascending order by value.

```
so = ReverseSortBy[list, Length]
```

{{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {x, x}, {a, a}, {e}, {d}}

A second step is needed to sort the single elements in ascending order.

```
SubsetMap[Sort, so, -Count[so, {_}] ;; -1]
```

{{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {x, x}, {a, a}, {d}, {e}}

The wanted result in one line:

```
SubsetMap[Sort, #, -Count[#, {_}] ;; -1] & @ ReverseSortBy[list, Length]
```

{{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {x, x}, {a, a}, {d}, {e}}

**My Question**

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {a, a}, {x, x}, {d}, {e}};

f[ key: 1, value_ ] := Splice @* Sort @ value
f[ key: _, value_ ] := Splice @* ReverseSort @ value

list // GroupBy[Length] /* KeyValueMap[f]

(* {{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {x, x}, {a, a}, {d}, {e}} *)
```

Comment: I don't know whether this is "easier," but I believe it to be rather "readable."

Comment: Yes, that's the style I like :)

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {a, a}, {x, x}, {d}, {e}};

MapThread[
  Compose, {{ReverseSort, Sort}, GatherBy[list, {Length@# > 1 &}]}] //
  Map[Apply[Sequence]]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {x, x}, {a, a}, {d}, {e}}

Comment: +1, very nice. Also: `Join @@ MapThread[#1@#2 &, ...`

Answer (score 7):

`Sort` can do that:

```
Sort[list, If[MatchQ[{##}, {{_}, {_}}], 1, -1] Order[#, #2] &]
(* {{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {x, x}, {a, a}, {d}, {e}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {a, a}, {x, x}, {d}, {e}};
```

Taking advantage (kind of a side effect) of the 3rd parameter of the `ReverseSortBy`:

```
ReverseSortBy[list, Length, Boole[# == 1] &]
```

> `{{c,c,c},{b,b,b},{x,x},{a,a},{d},{e}}`

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {a, a}, {x, x}, {d}, {e}};
```

---

Using `SplitBy` and `OrderedQ`:

```
f = Splice@If[OrderedQ@# && Last@*Dimensions@# > 1, Reverse@#, #] &;

f /@ SplitBy[list, Length]

(*{{c, c, c}, {b, b, b}, {x, x}, {a, a}, {d}, {e}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Join[Sort[Select[list,Length[#]>1&],OrderedQ[{#2,#1}]&],Sort[Select[list,Length[#]==1&]]]
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors.